# How to use Waves Transactions library in testnet?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, wavesplatform

I'm using Waves transactions library, I need to do some transaction testing using javascript and I would like to know how can I use it in testnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two things:

First, Some transactions have chainId as param. You need to pass 'T'. E.g:

```
const burnTx = burn({assetId:'someId', amount:1000, chainId:'T'})
```

Second, You send tx to testnet node. E.g:

```
await broadcast(burnTx, ' https://testnodes.wavesnodes.com')
```